# Cannot generate nationscript.bat - Tiger Geocoder

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geocoding, tiger

I have been attempting to install tiger - geocoder in a postgres database. After muddling through examples and resources online for days I have been able to conjure up this much of the workflow.

I understand I am now to find a nationscript.bat file in gisdata folder. It is not found.

Here is what I have tried so far...

create new db

```
CREATE DATABASE geocoder;
```

Install necessary extensions...

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
```

Grant permissions to tiger…

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA tiger TO PUBLIC; 
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA tiger_data TO PUBLIC;
GRANT SELECT, REFERENCES, TRIGGER 
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA tiger TO PUBLIC;
GRANT SELECT, REFERENCES, TRIGGER 
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA tiger_data TO PUBLIC;
GRANT EXECUTE 
ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA tiger TO PUBLIC;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA tiger_data 
GRANT SELECT,  REFERENCES 
ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;
```

Edited staging_fold field in tiger.loader_variables

1. Running sql cmd \!pwd to find home folder produces ‘c:\users\noah’
2. create new folders ‘gisdata’ and gisdata/temp inside home folder.
3. set staging_fold variable to ‘/gisdata’

I then edited declare_sect field in the tiger.loader_platform table such that...

```
SELECT declare_sect FROM tiger.loader_platform WHERE os='windows';
                  declare_sect
------------------------------------------------
 set TMPDIR=${staging_fold}\temp\
 set UNZIPTOOL="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
 set WGETTOOL="C:\wget-1.11.4\wget.exe"
 set PGBIN=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\
 set PGPORT=5432
 set PGHOST=localhost
 set PGUSER=postgres
 set PGPASSWORD=pass
 set PGDATABASE=tiger
 set PSQL="%PGBIN%psql"
 set SHP2PGSQL="%PGBIN%shp2pgsql"
 cd ${staging_fold}
```

Finally running these commands to Generate nationscript.bat

```
\t
\a
\o /gisdata/nationscript.bat
SELECT loader_generate_nation_script('windows');
\o
```

Which produces the following results...

```
geocoder=#   \o /gisdata/nationscript.bat
/gisdata/nationscript.bat: No such file or directory
geocoder=#     SELECT loader_generate_nation_script('windows');

                                    loader_generate_nation_script


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------
 set TMPDIR=\gisdata\temp\
 set UNZIPTOOL="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
 set WGETTOOL="C:\wget-1.11.4"
 set PGBIN=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\
 set PGPORT=5432
 set PGHOST=localhost
 set PGUSER=postgres
 set PGPASSWORD=pass
 set PGDATABASE=geocoder
 set PSQL="%PGBIN%psql"
 set SHP2PGSQL="%PGBIN%shp2pgsql"
 cd \gisdata

 cd \gisdata
 %WGETTOOL% ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/STATE/ --no-parent --relat
ive --recursive --level=1 --accept=zip --mirror --reject=html
 cd \gisdata/ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/STATE
 del %TMPDIR%\*.* /Q
 %PSQL% -c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS tiger_staging CASCADE;"
 %PSQL% -c "CREATE SCHEMA tiger_staging;"
 %PSQL% -c "DO language 'plpgsql' $$ BEGIN IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM informat
ion_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'tiger_data' ) THEN CREATE SCHEMA tiger_
data; END IF;  END $$"
 for /r %%z in (tl_*state.zip ) do %UNZIPTOOL% e %%z  -o%TMPDIR%
 cd %TMPDIR%
 %PSQL% -c "CREATE TABLE tiger_data.state_all(CONSTRAINT pk_state_all PRIMARY KE
Y (statefp),CONSTRAINT uidx_state_all_stusps  UNIQUE (stusps), CONSTRAINT uidx_s
tate_all_gid UNIQUE (gid) ) INHERITS(tiger.state); "
 %SHP2PGSQL% -D -c -s 4269 -g the_geom   -W "latin1" tl_2015_us_state.dbf tiger_
staging.state | %PSQL%
 %PSQL% -c "SELECT loader_load_staged_data(lower('state'), lower('state_all'));
"
         %PSQL% -c "CREATE INDEX tiger_data_state_all_the_geom_gist ON tiger_dat
a.state_all USING gist(the_geom);"
         %PSQL% -c "VACUUM ANALYZE tiger_data.state_all"
 cd \gisdata
 %WGETTOOL% ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/COUNTY/ --no-parent --rela
tive --recursive --level=1 --accept=zip --mirror --reject=html
 cd \gisdata/ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/COUNTY
 del %TMPDIR%\*.* /Q
 %PSQL% -c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS tiger_staging CASCADE;"
 %PSQL% -c "CREATE SCHEMA tiger_staging;"
 %PSQL% -c "DO language 'plpgsql' $$ BEGIN IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM informat
ion_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'tiger_data' ) THEN CREATE SCHEMA tiger_
data; END IF;  END $$"
 for /r %%z in (tl_*county.zip ) do %UNZIPTOOL% e %%z  -o%TMPDIR%
 cd %TMPDIR%
 %PSQL% -c "CREATE TABLE tiger_data.county_all(CONSTRAINT pk_tiger_data_county_a
ll PRIMARY KEY (cntyidfp),CONSTRAINT uidx_tiger_data_county_all_gid UNIQUE (gid)
  ) INHERITS(tiger.county); "
 %SHP2PGSQL% -D -c -s 4269 -g the_geom   -W "latin1" tl_2015_us_county.dbf tiger
_staging.county | %PSQL%
 %PSQL% -c "ALTER TABLE tiger_staging.county RENAME geoid TO cntyidfp;  SELECT l
oader_load_staged_data(lower('county'), lower('county_all'));"
         %PSQL% -c "CREATE INDEX tiger_data_county_the_geom_gist ON tiger_data.c
ounty_all USING gist(the_geom);"
         %PSQL% -c "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_tiger_data_county_all_statefp_count
yfp ON tiger_data.county_all USING btree(statefp,countyfp);"
         %PSQL% -c "CREATE TABLE tiger_data.county_all_lookup ( CONSTRAINT pk_co
unty_all_lookup PRIMARY KEY (st_code, co_code)) INHERITS (tiger.county_lookup);"
         %PSQL% -c "VACUUM ANALYZE tiger_data.county_all;"
         %PSQL% -c "INSERT INTO tiger_data.county_all_lookup(st_code, state, co_
code, name) SELECT CAST(s.statefp as integer), s.abbrev, CAST(c.countyfp as inte
ger), c.name FROM tiger_data.county_all As c INNER JOIN state_lookup As s ON s.s
tatefp = c.statefp;"
         %PSQL% -c "VACUUM ANALYZE tiger_data.county_all_lookup;"
(1 row)
```

But still nothing is produced in gisdata folder and none of the tables above are produced in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind , I found the issue.  Apparently the \o /gisdata/nationscript.bat 
argument needed a full path.

```
\o c:/users/noah/gisdata/nationscript.bat
```

worked to generate the script.

Also learned that the root folder referred to by the geocoder was c:/. All of the tiger files were extracted to c:/gisdata
Thus correcting the above to 
\o c:/gisdata/nationscript.bat